# Allocate a new structure initializes it with the provided parameters

Tags: c, pointers, structure, allocation

I want to create a structure in which represents a people.
So i started declare a structure People that contains 3 fields: - firstname : a pointer to a string which represents the first name - lastname : a pointer to a string that represents the name and
age : an integer representing the age.

Now i have to write a function which allocates a new People structure and initializes it with copies of the provided parameters.

The problem i have is that the program always crashes. I dont understand well how can i fill the structure without crashing (thats an online compiler by my school).
Can someone explain and correct me please ?

This is how its looks like :

**Array.h :**

```c
#ifndef _PEOPLE_H_                                           
#define _PEOPLE_H_                                           
                                             
typedef struct {                                             
    char* firstname;                                             
    char* lastname;                                          
    int age;                                             
} People;                                            
                                             
People* createPeople(char* firstname, char*  lastname, int age);                                             
                                             
#endif
```

**Array.c :**

```c
#include "People.h"                                          
People* createPeople(char* firstname, char*  lastname, int age) {                                            
    People people1;                                          
                                             
    people1.firstname = firstname;                                           
    people1.lastname = lastname;                                             
    people1.age = age;                                           
}
```

Comment: Crank up your warnings since you're not `return`ing anything in `createPeople`.  Also be aware that `people1` is a local object, so you can't safely `return` its address.

Comment: Your function creates and initializes a `People` object on the stack, but then does not return any value despite the function returning a pointer. Your compiler should be rejecting this program or at the very least issuing a warning. This is undefined behavior. If you want to allocate dynamically, then call `malloc` to obtain a pointer to a sufficiently-large chunk of memory (`sizeof(People)`), then initialize that memory and actually return the pointer.

Comment: You can't return a pointer to a local variable. If you want to return a pointer, you need to allocate it dynamically with `malloc()`.

Comment: And it's likely that you also need to make copies of the `firstname` and `lastname` strings before saving them into the structure, unless the caller allocates them dynamically. Otherwise you might pointers to the same strings in all the `Person` instances, or the pointers might become invalid when leaving the caller's scope.

Comment: So how can I turn the structure around? If not, is the declaration of the value assignment good?

Comment: This kind of thing is covered early in any reputable introductory book on C programming.

Comment: OT: An instance of this structure contains the details about one **Person**. The name `People` is deceptive as it means many persons...

Comment: here is my code now : `
```c
#include "People.h"                     
#include <stdlib.h>                     
                     
People* createPeople(char* firstname, char*  lastname, int age) {                     
    People *people = malloc(sizeof(People));                     
                     
    people->firstname = firstname;                     
    people->lastname = lastname;                     
    people->age = age;                     
    return people;                     
}                     
```

Comment: OT (again): If this facility is to grow to a full app with persistent storage, it would be better to record the individual's birthdate than their "age"... One is constant, the other changes as the record gets older. I'm not 19 anymore, in spite of all my wishes...

Answer (score 2):

You cannot return a pointer to a local variable as it is out of scope upon return of function.  This means you either need to pass in an instance of Person, or as here, use `malloc()` to dynamically allocate an instance.  I also called `strdup()` on the two strings, in this example it is not required, but the `createPeople()` function doesn't know when the objects they point to are out of scope.  Minor issue, People is plural, but you only create a a Person.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char* firstname;
    char* lastname;
    int age;
} Person;

Person* createPerson(char* firstname, char*  lastname, int age) {
    Person *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
    if(!p) return NULL;
    p->firstname = strdup(firstname);
    p->lastname= strdup(lastname);
    p->age = age;
    return p;
}

int main() {
    Person *p = createPerson("Clark", "Kent", 42);
    free(p->firstname);
    free(p->lastname);
    free(p);
}
```

Comment: FWIW, I find `p[0]` more understandable than `*p`.  Here makes little difference here, yet clearer in more complex cases.

Answer (score 0):

You first have to include `stdlib.h` to be able to use `malloc` and `free`. Then you allocate enough memory to hold the `struct People` using `malloc`.

If the memory allocation fails you  return `NULL`.

If the memory allocation goes well, then you assign each member of the struct value and return it.

```
#include "People.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
                                          
People* createPeople(char* firstname, char*  lastname, int age) {                                            
    People *people1 = malloc(sizeof(*people1));
    if (!people1)
         return (NULL);                             
    people1->firstname = firstname;                                           
    people1->lastname = lastname;                                             
    people1->age = age;

   return (people1);                                           
}
```

Comment: @MaxwellD.Dorliea Super minor thing but the () around return values is kinda weird.  Otherwise good answer.  Maybe write a destroy function?  It will be a little different than my answer.

Comment: @AllanWind "but the () around return values is kinda weird." --> Agreed.  `()` around `*p` in [`sizeof(*p)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75089302/2410359) is also not needed.  As with such style issues, code to your group's coding style.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I updated my answer to remove the () for sizeof... less is better.  it's usage is somewhat surprising.  () is required for types, but not for unary-expression (6.5.3), yet you can use () for an expression in which case it's a regular old () and instead what looks like a function call.